# Language fallback not working for a specific language

Tags: language-fallback

We have set up language fallback for our multilingual multi-site in Sitecore. We are using 3 languages `da, de, and en`. `en` is the fallback version for other languages. Fallback is working fine for da but not working for de. Any help will be appreciated.

We have already created a patch file including the following lines:

```
    <site name="website" hostName="site1">
    <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>

  </site>

     <site name="website2" hostName="site2">
    <patch:attribute name="enableItemLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableFieldLanguageFallback">true</patch:attribute>

  </site>
```

and enabled fallback in standard values. Anything else I need to do to achieve this `Sitecore version (8.2)`

Comment: You may need to provide more info like how it was setup etc. given info may not be helpful.

Comment: Also what version of sitecore ? I've experienced problems with language fallback before, in which a restart of the instance fixes the problem.

Comment: Added more pieces of information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may have already done it but cant resist telling that the fallback language also needs to be done at Language level - 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things you can check:

1. As noted in another answer, ensure the fallback language value is set in your "de" language item.
2. Be sure to add the patch attributes to the "shell" site definition as well, or you won't see the fallback work properly in the editor.
3. You also need to turn language fallback on with the search indexes; the standard configurations have them explicitly set to false.